# Use OpenSSH on Windows Server and connect as "NT Authority\SYSTEM"

Tags: windows, ssh, virtual-machine, openssh

> Note on security: What I'm about to ask happens in an isolated environment, cut off from the Internet and the immediate LAN.

**I'd like to SSH into a Windows Server and end up executing commands as the LocalSystem account on the target Windows Server.**

I'm using OpenSSH on a target Windows Server 2022 DataCenter VM inside a local Hyper-V. The target VM is not part of any AD domain. The client machine coincides with the Hyper-V host.

The SSH client application is an automated black box ([the Remote Testing feature of Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/remote-testing?view=vs-2022)). It's only configurable concerning the target host port and username. Making it PSEXEC its way into executing commands as LocalSystem right after connecting as a regular admin is impossible.

I've successfully employed private/public key authentication, and I can SSH into the Windows Server's .\Administrator account.

Does anyone know if connecting as LocalSystem is possible?
I've been researching the problem a lot, and no article I could find either confirms or infirms the possibility.

I've employed the `administrators_authorized_keys` configuration file in `ProgramData/ssh` and `authorized_keys` in `Windows/System32/config/systemprofile/.ssh` ("the LocalSystem user profile"/.ssh), but to no avail.

I should point out that OpenSSH runs as a LocalService, but it should know to not create a child process as a different user in this particular case. Also, specifying the username in the SSH.exe seems problematic. I've tried everything from, the Machine Name itself, System, LocalSystem, the well-known SID `S-1-5-18`, etc..

> For anyone interested in why this is a desire, I can briefly summarize it, and I'll respond to further questions in the comments: My team and I are creating a software system in .NET, and our end-product is delivered as a Windows Service. Regarding unit and integration tests, we want to use Visual Studio's capability of running tests on a remote Windows Server. Our setup involves an isolated target VM running in Hyper-V.

Comment: Clarification shouldn’t be provided within a comment but by editing your question. So if anyone has a need for clarification you should edit your question instead of submitting a comment.  Commentary are temporary, and often, they will be cleared in mass. An alternative is to create a user account Nvidia does something similar. Your probably running into the fact that LocalSystem doesn’t have a user profile, which is fine, provided you configure some other location as where they key owned by LocalSystem exists. However, I don’t believe that LocalSystem is your traditional user account.